# My site has been hacked. I have managed to clean it up. But now, most of my links are looping back to the home page

Tags: craft2

My site was hacked by a Russian hacker. I know because the characters were Russian on one of the files he left. I have cleaned up the site, but many of the links are looping back to the home page. What can I do to fix this? Thanks

I have Craft 2.3, php 7.1, mysql, and here is the site: camp.gsnorcal.org

Appreciate your feedback

Comment: You seem to know a lot about this hacker based on just a few characters left behind...? It’s most likely an automated script that managed to penetrate the site. Follow @4midori’s advice and upgrade to a supported version of Craft.

Answer (score 3):

There was a [bug in Craft 4 mentioning RCE vulnerabilities](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4415---2023-07-03-critical), and I saw the same results of hacking on my site(s), but I'm not sure about such an old version of Craft.

Can you restore the site from a previous database backup? You will need to find a backup that predates the hack.
After that, I would suggest:

- Upgrade to the latest point release for Craft 2, better yet, make a plan to upgrade all the way to Craft version 4.
- Reset all user passwords, and review all permissions and delete all unneeded accounts

Maybe others can chime in here with additional security suggestions.

Comment: Agreed. Craft 2 hasn’t been updated in over 3 years and Craft 2.3 is over 8 years old.